# R data.table join equivalent to pandas merge.asof

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of pandas [merge_asof](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table.express/vignettes/joins.html) using a [data.table join](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table.express/vignettes/joins.html).

```
left <- data.table(a = c(1, 5, 10), left_val = c("a", "b", "c"))
right <- data.table(aa = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7), right_val = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7))
```

My expected result is this, similar to a left join but matching backwards, i.e first match where `right$aa <= left$a`

```
pd.merge_asof(left, right, on="a")
    a left_val  right_val
0   1        a          1
1   5        b          3
2  10        c          7
```

I tried this non-equijoin without success. I'd like to keep the syntax `data.table` or `dplyr` related

```
left[right, on = .(a >= aa), nomatch = NULL]
 a left_val right_val
1: 1        a         1
2: 1        b         1
3: 1        c         1
4: 2        b         2
5: 2        c         2
6: 3        b         3
7: 3        c         3
8: 6        c         6
9: 7        c         7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use data.table `roll` parameter. A value of `TRUE` or `+Inf` here means previous value carried forward (or backward from the join point as it is your point of view).

```
right[left, on= .("aa"="a"), roll=+Inf]

       aa right_val left_val
   <num>     <num>   <char>
1:     1         1        a
2:     5         3        b
3:    10         7        c
```

Comment: thanks, compared to my answer which approach is preferable you think?

Comment: No idea :-) Should be compared on edge cases. Also providing for `roll` finite positive or negative number limits how far values are carried forward or backward (from doc). There is also `rollends` parameter that allows to take care of very first and very last values. I would say that using `roll` gives more control.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this out there for future reference

```
> right[left, on = .(aa <= a), .(a, left_val, right_val), mult="last"]
    a left_val right_val
1:  1        a         1
2:  5        b         3
3: 10        c         7
```